# How to get the client requested url where the request is coming in the ASP.NET web api?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

In My application the scenario like i want to read the client requested URL from ASP.NET WEB API.

Example:

https://xxx.test.com/test.html page is calling https://api.test.com/api/home/get/1 WEB method.

The requested url https://xxx.test.com/test.html need to read from the web method.

The below code is returning IP Address. It is not returning domain url.

```
// GET api/home/get/5
public string Get(int id)
{
return HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
}
```

Please suggest me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I have added the code. Pl see and suggest me.

Comment: Can you update the JS on test.html to pass the requesting URL on a custom HTTP header perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

Look to `HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.OriginalString`.  Note that this data was set by the client, so you can't trust it's 100% accurate.

Comment: It is giving error. I think it should be HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.OriginalString

Comment: Good catch.  HttpContext.Current...  If the browser didn't pass it, UrlReferrer could be null.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
// http://localhost:1302/TESTERS/Default6.aspx

string path = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
// /TESTERS/Default6.aspx

string host = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host;
// localhost
```

Comment: It is not working in hosted servers.In local host it is working. In servers it is returning same url of web method.

Comment: Voted up for the comments about URL format each property represents.

Answer (score 1):

If you're behind a load balancer or other reverse proxy, when asking for `HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress`, you won't get the IP of the client, instead you'll get the IP of the load balancer.  In that case, look to `HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"]` for the browser's IP address.  Note that if you aren't behind such hardware, this is a great attack vector.

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"] This is also giving null value.

Comment: X-Forwarded-For will be null if you're not behind a load balancer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `HttpRequest.UrlReferrer`. The MSDN reference can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx)